# Unable to register my application with Google Developers

Tags: console, youtube-api, cloud, registering

In my endeavour to gain use of the Youtube API I am required to follow the procedure defined [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

In this link there exists a Prerequisites section that states:

> Register your application with Google so that it can submit API
> requests.

This takes me [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) which is a page Titled: "Registering your Application". This page contains instructions stating:

> To register a new application, do the following:
>
> 1. Enter the Google Cloud Console https: //cloud.google.com/console [hit my link limit LOL]
> 2. Select a project, or create a new one.
> 3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.
> 4. In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.

I have done all of the above. I have also clicked on the project taking me to another page. I am however, unable to register the application.

My question to you is "Where do I find the "Registered apps" because it's not in the sidebar on the left.

Google even provide a video on the instructional page stepping you through it. Unfortunately the video appears to be for an older site.

I am running Firefox 25.0.1. and it doesn't work for me so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Registered Apps, in new version you'll go Credentials under API's and Auth and create your keys there.

Comment: It would not be that difficult for Google to update their documents.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything to help you out but i couldn't find "Registered Apps" too. Have you ever tried "Credentials" ?  I think it works for the same way.

They don't care much about updates i guess. That's why they did not renew the instructions and the video..